# Reopen question now closed as duplicate, since the question it is pointing to has been deleted?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, exact-duplicates

Shouldn't [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35933/how-to-eliminate-prairie-dog-colonies-from-a-field) on the hunting of prairie dogs be reopened, since it is now closed as a duplicate and the question it is pointing to has been deleted? To have questions closed as duplicates only makes sense if they point to a question that is clearly asking about the same thing, that ideally has usuful answers. To have duplicate pointers that doesn't lead to anything puts the question marked as duplicate "in limbo", since it cannot get an answer but at the same time it hasn't been labelled as off-topic either. I have already flagged the question to the moderators and pointed this out, but so far nothing has happened.

For the record, I don't think that the question should have been closed as a duplicate in the first place (the original question by the same poster should have been edited instead of posting a second question though). If users feel that the question linked above should be closed for another reason this would still be possible, but that should be decided in a new voting process, which would also provide feedback to the OP. Only having the question closed as a duplicate clearly doesn't do this.

Comment: Once you have cast a vote you cannot cast again (mods exempted). So reopen-reclose cycle does not really work and other set of users would have to close the question. So if a question is closed for a wrongful reason-**A** but will nonetheless be closed for a correct reason-**B**, then reopening and closing is not worth the effort. I feel this question still needs some work. As you mentioned in the other post this question is not *biologically relevant and meaningful* yet.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Are you sure that new votes cannot be cast in a new voting process (i.e. after the Q has been reopened)? I highly doubt it, but might be mistaken. I know that voting cannot be changed during a close-vote process (so they cannot be recast), but my understanding was that each close-vote process starts from scratch. I agree that the Q isn't perfect, but that doesn't change the fact that the current situation doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Once a user has cast a vote they cannot cast again. If you have voted to close and then the post was reopened then you cannot again cast a close vote. Also, if you retract your close vote, you cannot VTC again.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Ok, then I was mistaken. In this case, reopening will only affect one single user though from what I can see (AliceD), so it wouldn't affect a new close-vote process that much.

Comment: So the question should probably be closed, but the reason why it's closed has changed. Is there a process for changing close reasons somewhere? I can't imagine we're the first SE site to have this problem.